# Saving API call result to a collection but recieving errors while setting up a SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I have a Meteor method which does an API call, then the response of the call is saved to the users collection. I'm using the [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) package with my project and I'm a little bit lost setting up my [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) for this.

Here is what the JSON response looks like from the API call:

> [{"keyword":"2i","url":"http://example.com","title":"Example","timestamp":"2016-11-05
>   08:54:42","ip":"00.00.00.000","clicks":"2","user":"HweoSCY2ujscjJ9Zl"},{"keyword":"2j","url":"http://example.com","title":"YouTube","timestamp":"2016-11-06
>   02:11:18","ip":"00.00.00.000","clicks":"1","user":"HweoSCY2ujscjJ9Zl"},{"keyword":"2k","url":"http://example.com","title":"YouTube","timestamp":"2016-11-08
>   03:35:12","ip":"00.00.00.000","clicks":"0","user":"HweoSCY2ujscjJ9Zl"}]

Here's currently how I've been able to save this data to the users collection:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
  $set: { 'shortURLs.URLS': result.data }
});
```

This works and looks like this in the db:

[image: screenshot]

My issue is that I'd like to have a SimpleSchema setup for this so that the "timestamp" will be saved as a Date instead of a String, but everytime I try and create a schema for it I just receive errors like `"After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty"`. I have tried a lot of different variations to try and make it work but none of them have been successful, here's just currently where it's at:

```
Schema.ShortURLs = new SimpleSchema({
    shortURLs: {
        type: Object
    },
    'shortURLs.$': {
        type: Object
    },
    'shortURLs.$.keyword': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Keyword"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.url': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "URL"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.title': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Title"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.timestamp': {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        label: "Timestamp"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.ip': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "IP"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.clicks': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Clicks"
    },
    'shortURLs.$.user': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "User"
    },
});
```

This is then attached apart of a User Simple Schema:

```
...
shortURLs: {
    type: Schema.ShortURLs,
    optional: true
},
...
```

And I have that attached to the users collection:

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

I don't think there's an issue with how I have it attached as I have other SimpleSchemas setup the same way and they're working fine, I believe the issue is how I have this particular one written. Any help here would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the shortURLs type in the Meteor.users collection as `type: [Schema.ShortURLs]`, i.e. a list of type `Schema.ShortURLs`

```
Schema = {}
Schema.ShortURLs = new SimpleSchema({
    keyword: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Keyword"
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "URL"
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Title"
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        label: "Timestamp"
    },
    ip: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "IP"
    },
    clicks: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Clicks"
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "User"
    },
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
...
  shortURLs: {
      type: [Schema.ShortURLs],
      optional: true
  },
...
});

...

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I managed to get it working with this. I just have one question, whenever I call this method now I see a message like this appear in my console for each array: `"SimpleSchema.clean: autoconverted value 2016-11-11 23:44:28 from string to object for shortURLs.$.timestamp"`. Do you know of a better way to go about this? In some cases the API result returns 100+ so seeing this pop up that many times makes me think I'm probably not doing something right/most efficiently, but maybe I'm wrong. Any input is very appreciated, thanks again! :)

Comment: This is normal, as the raw type of the date value returned from the api is a String.  You can stop this by setting `SimpleSchema.debug = false`, but may also miss other warnings from the SimpleSchema package.